# Is China going to be added to the list of countries eligible for working holidays in Australia as part of the upcoming visa changes?

Tags: australia, china, working-holiday, chinese-citizens

This year USA and China changed their reciprocal visa rules making it easier for their people to visit the other country with visas lasting much longer.

I've heard that something similar is in the works between Australia and China.

Do we know if part of these upcoming changes will allow Chinese citizens to come to Australia on working holiday visas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well this is a shocker for me but it seems like Australia got around to implementing this much more quickly than I would've expected.

[An article I just found on an expat forum](https://www.forum-expat-management.com/article/2015/09/17/australia-china-china-added-to-australian-work-and-holiday-visa-program) states that China was added to the list exactly one week ago:

> **Australia has added China to the list of countries whose citizens are eligible for Work and Holiday Visas.**
>
> **Implementation time frame:** 21 September.

And there's only going to be 5,000 places per year for a country with an enormous population. So Chinese friends, apply now!

---

Update: My friend in China chased this up and tells me they only released the first 1,500 spots so far and those were all gone within minutes! No word so far on when the next batch of spots will become available.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty competitive visa, but I guess Australia has a pretty small population.

Comment: I wonder how it compares to the quotas for other countries. Our gov. is probably worried about a flood of Chinese overstaying or finding some loophole so they're starting with small numbers.

Comment: to compare, NZ's quota for 2015/2016 was 1000 places.  And Aus has about 5x population of NZ

Comment: @EdmundYeung99: Thanks. But I was actually wondering how many spots Australia offers to other countries rather than how many spots other countries offer to China. Though that's also interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, the political atmosphere isn't that positive with regards to Asians, or working holiday visas. I'm not surprised this quota is very small.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: That's why I'm wondering what the quotas are for Japanese and Koreans.

Comment: @hippietrail and the Taiwanese. I remember Taiwanese people often appearing in the 4 Corners doco "Slaving Away".

Comment: Link to 4 Corners "Slaving Away": http://www.abc.net.au/4corners/slaving-away-promo/6437876